# Local constant variable is not constexpr evaluatable, but can't figure out why

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, constexpr

I'm trying to take an int as a parameter and operate on it's bytes individually, for example take 0xDEADF00D and handle each byte one by one: 0xDE 0xAD 0xF0 0x0D

To do this, I've done the following code:

```
template <int state, int seed>
constexpr static uint32_t CalculateRandomFromState()
{
    const char bytes[4] = {
        (state >> 24) & 0xFF,
        (state >> 16) & 0xFF,
        (state >> 8) & 0xFF,
         state & 0xFF,
    };

    constexpr auto value = Compiletime::Hash<seed, sizeof(bytes)>(bytes);

    return value;
}
```

The sig of the HashFn is:

```
template <const uint32_t seed, const uint32_t size = NULL>
constexpr uint32_t Hash(const char* message)
```

Compilation fails with:

> error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
>
> note: failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime
>
> note: see usage of 'bytes'

I've read topics here on StackOverflow about parameters might not be able to evaluate at compile time, *(that's why I switched most of my parameters to template variable, so it's 100% guaranteed they are compile time)* but in this case it doesn't seem to be logical why it gives an error. The `bytes` value is dependent on a compile time value, also byte is a constant.

Why would it be outside of it's lifetime? If I put let's say `"somestring"` instead of the variable `bytes` then it compiles perfectly.
What is not constant evaluatable here?

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] so that it can be reproduced? Also which version of VS and MSVC are you using?

Comment: The variable `bytes` is `const` but not `constexpr`. It's created and recreated and initialized each time `CalculateRandomFromState` is called. Can you make it `constexpr` instead? Then perhaps you could pass it as a template argument also?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nNovgD).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Isn't it implicitly `constexpr` due to being `const` and having a `constexpr` initialzier?

Comment: Also remember that `constexpr` is similar to `inline`, it's a *hint* for the compiler, but the compiler can disregard it.

Comment: I was using Visual Studio 2015 v15.9.8
Also when I added constexpr instead of const, it worked. I'm not yet exactly sure why. I'll try to make a reproducible simple version of it. It's quite interesting why the code done by @HolyBlackCat is working, while my isn't. As soon as I can reproduce it online I'll post it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - the error appears when you actually [attempt to compute the hash](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/lHwP_Z).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is for the function, but can that happen that I call a constexpr function and assign it to a constexpr variable, eg.:

```constexpr auto a = somecexprfn();```

and it is not calculated at compile time? According to my knowledge no, but I'm interested if so.

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, why the `value` variable? It's not really needed (with the code as you show it).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You're right, it's completely unnecessary, I just used as debugging while writing the code and left it as is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`constexpr` on a function declaration does not require all evaluation paths to lead to a constant expression. Whether or not the result of a function call is `constexpr` can depend on the input arguments.

Assuming your Hash function looks like this:

```
template <uint32_t seed, uint32_t size>
constexpr uint32_t Hash(const char* message)
{
    uint32_t rc = seed;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        rc += message[i];
    return rc;
}
```

This will evaluate to a constant expression iff `message` is a constant expression.

But you're invoking it with a non-constant expression:

```
    const char bytes[4] = {
        (state >> 24) & 0xFF,
        (state >> 16) & 0xFF,
        (state >> 8) & 0xFF,
         state & 0xFF,
    };

    constexpr auto value = Compiletime::Hash<seed, sizeof(bytes)>(bytes);
```

Every time `Hash(bytes)` is called, `bytes` will potentially have a different address.

You can make it work by simply declaring `bytes` `constexpr`:

```
template <int state, int seed>
constexpr static uint32_t CalculateRandomFromState()
{
    constexpr char bytes[4] = {
        (state >> 24) & 0xFF,
        (state >> 16) & 0xFF,
        (state >> 8) & 0xFF,
         state & 0xFF,
    };

    constexpr auto value = Compiletime::Hash<seed, sizeof(bytes)>(bytes);

    return value;
}
```